Binary Audio data into .wav Format
I am working on a React-Flask project where I am sending recorded audio file as Base64 to flask. I'm converting this Base64 to Binary and writing in file which I later on want to serve to frontend again in .wav format.
I am able convert Bsee64 to Binary and write in a .wav file. When I send this .wav audio file to frontend, it does not work an gives Not Found error (even the path to file which i am serving is correct)
Here is the flask implementation:
@app.route('/upload_audio', methods=['POST'])
def upload_audio():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        base64_audio = data.get('base64Data')
        print(base64_audio)
        if base64_audio:
            audio_binary = base64.b64decode(base64_audio)
            filename = f'recorded_audio_{uuid.uuid4().hex}.webm'
            #print(filename)
            #print(audio_binary)
            audio_file_path = f'./audios_tmp/{filename}'
            print(audio_file_path)
            with open(audio_file_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(audio_binary)
            audio_output = f'local_host:PORT/audios_tmp/{filename}'
            print(audio_output)
            return jsonify({'audio_location': audio_output})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': str(e)}), 400


You mention a .wav file, but you write a .webm file. Furthermore, you are using a directory other than the static folder, which suggests that you are using another route to serve the file, but you have not specified it in the code. Assuming the file is playable locally, some information is missing to help you with this problem. The error cannot be narrowed down otherwise.
